# javascript script no working adding classlist to an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, dom-events

i am trying to make a quiz app with javascript but it does not work i want when i click on one of the option if it is the first option i wanna set its class to correct and the others to in-correct but it does not work for me i do not know where is the problem or what i did wrong , ...

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="icon" href="./../images/quizapp.png" type="image" >

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./../css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./../css/default.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./../css/quizap.css">

<title>Document</title>
```

```
<header class="container p-4 text-center border">

    <h1 class="h1 text-danger">Quiz Application With JavaScript</h1>

</header>

<div class="container landing p-5 mt-3 text-center">

    <div class="description m-auto">

        <h2 class="h2 border text-center p-3">Welcome To The Quiz App...</h2>

    </div>

    <div class="collection container" id="categorie">

        <div class="row mt-5 container">

            <div class="col-4 categories text-center" id="sports">

                Sports

            </div>

            <div class="col-4 categories text-center" id="music">

                Music

            </div>

            <div class="col-4 categories text-center" id="food" >

                General

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="question" id="sports_question">

        <div class="list_questions list-group" id="answers">

            <li class="list-group-item">

                <h3 class="h3">

                    <div id="firstQuestion" class="container q_container">

                        <div class="card my-card">

                            <div class="card-body ">

                                <h5 class="card-title">Who Is My Favorite FootBall Team?</h5>

                                <p class="card-text options">

                                    <div class="option_one option" value="1">Wydad</div>

                                    <div class="option_two option" value="0">Raja</div>

                                    <div class="option_thre option" value="0">Mat</div>

                                    <div class="option_frour option" value="0">Fus</div>

                                </p>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </h3>

            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item">

                <h3 class="h3">

                    <div id="firstQuestion" class="container q_container">

                        <div class="card my-card">

                            <div class="card-body ">

                                <h5 class="card-title">Who Is My Favorite FootBall Team?</h5>

                                <p class="card-text options">

                                    <div class="option_one option">Wydad</div>

                                    <div class="option_two option">Raja</div>

                                    <div class="option_thre option">Mat</div>

                                    <div class="option_frour option">Fus</div>

                                </p>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </h3>

            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item">

                <h3 class="h3">

                    <div id="firstQuestion" class="container q_container">

                        <div class="card my-card">

                            <div class="card-body ">

                                <h5 class="card-title">Who Is My Favorite FootBall Team?</h5>

                                <p class="card-text options">

                                    <div class="option_one option">Wydad</div>

                                    <div class="option_two option">Raja</div>

                                    <div class="option_thre option">Mat</div>

                                    <div class="option_frour option">Fus</div>

                                </p>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </h3>

            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item">

                <h3 class="h3">

                    <div id="firstQuestion" class="container q_container">

                        <div class="card my-card">

                            <div class="card-body ">

                                <h5 class="card-title">Who Is My Favorite FootBall Team?</h5>

                                <p class="card-text options">

                                    <div class="option_one option">Wydad</div>

                                    <div class="option_two option">Raja</div>

                                    <div class="option_thre option">Mat</div>

                                    <div class="option_frour option">Fus</div>

                                </p>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </h3>

            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item">

                <h3 class="h3">

                        <div id="firstQuestion" class="container q_container">

                        <div class="card my-card">

                            <div class="card-body ">

                                <h5 class="card-title">Who Is My Favorite FootBall Team?</h5>

                                <p class="card-text options">

                                    <div class="option_one option">Wydad</div>

                                    <div class="option_two option">Raja</div>

                                    <div class="option_thre option">Mat</div>

                                    <div class="option_frour option">Fus</div>

                                </p>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </h3>

            </li>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<script src="./../script/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="./../script/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="./../script/quizap.js"></script>
```

and this is the javascript code:

```
let categories = document.querySelectorAll('.categories');


let sports_question = document.getElementById('sports_question');


let collection = document.getElementById('categorie');


let options = document.querySelectorAll('.list_questions');


let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.question');



for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {

  options[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    const selectedOption = e.target;

    console.log(selectedOption);

    const correct = selectedOption.dataset.correct;

    Array.from(options[i].children).forEach(option => {

        SetStatus(option, option.dataset.correct);

        console.log(option.dataset.correct + 'this is the option');

    });
  })

}
function SetStatus(option, correct) {

  if (correct) {

    option.classList.add('correct');

  } else {

    option.classList.add('in-correct');

  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {

  categories[i].addEventListener('click', function () {

    sports_question.classList.toggle('active');

    collection.classList.toggle('hide');

  })

}
```

Comment: there's a issue in `let options = document.querySelectorAll('.list_questions');` why are you using `querySelectorAll` when there is only a single div of class `.list_questions`?

Comment: how can i fix my noob error ...?

Comment: did you copy your code somewhere? 

Comment: no that is mine :( i know its not clean and clear im new in javascript

Answer (score 1):

First
The div tag can NOT be inside p tag, because the paragraph will be broken at the point, where the div tag is entered.

So change p and div into ul and li

HTML

```
<ul class="card-text options">
    <li class="option_one option" value="1">Wydad</li>
    <li class="option_two option" value="0">Raja</li>
    <li class="option_thre option" value="0">Mat</li>
    <li class="option_frour option" value="0">Fus</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
const options = document.querySelectorAll(".option");

(function addEventListeners() {
  options.forEach((option) => {
    option.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      const { parentNode } = event.target;

      setClasses(parentNode, option);
    });
  });
})();

function setClasses({ children }, selected) {
  [...children].forEach((child) => {
    if (child !== selected) {
      child.classList.add("in-correct");
      child.classList.remove("correct");
      return;
    }
    child.classList.remove("in-correct");
    child.classList.add("correct");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

querySelector all returns nodeList not array of elements.
use spread operator to convert them to array.
here's an example

```
let options = [...document.querySelectorAll('.list_questions')];
```

Comment: there is no need to do this when there is only a single element of respective `className` present.

Comment: I'm assuming since it's a quiz he may add more questions

Comment: I too agree He should add clear code. js is also messy some inside code block some isn't.

Comment: i m new in javascript i appologize for my messy code im just trying to learn

Comment: Just Add all codes together as in files. and add their file name before code.

Comment: here's an example.
index.html ```<html></html>```
script.js ```alert("this is js file")```